# Why an IF statement is being infringed while output results clearly says it should be executed?

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, simulink, s-function

Context: I'm using Matlab/Simulink to simulate a circuit where I need to [follow a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5jdZ.png). To simplify it: below reference current then apply more current, above reference current then apply less current. To achieve this, I have to control [two devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWTc.png) (Sa and Sb) which basically closes applying a 1 in my code and opens with a 0 (both at the same time).

Now, I'm having [these results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GC0W.png) where the important graphs are S1 Current, S-Function/2 and S-Function/1 and the final question: why, considering the following code, would the S-Function/2, this is THY[], stay at 1 while clearly there are lapses of time where S-Function/1, this is IGBT[], is 0?

- The next code is inside an S-Function that I use inside Simulink. [This is the entire code](https://pastebin.com/aeD3RfZQ)

  ```
  for (i=0; i<width; i++){
  if (*Is[i] <  *Iref[i]){
      //IGBT[] is S-Function/1 and THY[] is S-Function/2
      //Is[] is S1 Current and Iref[] is Reference Current 1
      IGBT[i] = 1.0;

      if ( IGBT[i] == 0.0){
      THY[i] = 0.0;   
      }
      else {
      THY[i] = 1.0; 
      }
      }
      else {
      IGBT[i] = 0.0;   
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think there is a problem in code:

```
for (i=0; i<width; i++){
if (*Is[i] <  *Iref[i]){
    //IGBT[] is S-Function/1 and THY[] is S-Function/2
    //Is[] is S1 Current and Iref[] is Reference Current 1
    IGBT[i] = 1.0;

    if ( IGBT[i] == 0.0){ // condition 1
    // if condition 1 is true then execute this
    THY[i] = 0.0;   
    }
    else {
    // if condition 1 is false then execute this
    THY[i] = 1.0; 
    }
    }
    else {
   // this condition will never be executed
    IGBT[i] = 0.0;   
    }
}
```

Now if condition 1 is true then `THY[I] = 0.0;` will be executed, if condition is false then, `THY[i] = 1.0;`. In your code

```
 else {
    IGBT[i] = 0.0;   
    }
```

is a kind of dead code and it will never be excuted. You need to replace the `else` followed by `if` condition with `else if(condition)` so that second else can be executed.

Also 1 more thing

```
IGBT[i] = 1.0; // IGBT[i] is updated

        if ( IGBT[i] == 0.0){ // IGBT[i]  is compared ... wow
```

I would recommend you to read about comparison between float and double.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
IGBT[i] = 1.0;

if ( IGBT[i] == 0.0) {
    THY[i] = 0.0;         // <--- will never be executed
}
else {
    THY[i] = 1.0; 
}
```

Assuming it's executed sequentially (i.e. no threads), You **always** sets `IGBT[i]` to be `1` and then the `else` part will be executed resulting in `THY[i]` equals `1`, and therefore always stays `1`.